# can't connect to ethernet connection on 16.10

Tags: networking, 16.10, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu and don't know what to install and what to remove.Usually i search on web and do that. Accidentally i entered some command and now i can't connect to my wired connection.
It shows

> Ethernet Network() device not managed

Also there is one more line shows

> Ethernet Network(Marvell 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller) device not managed

when i try to run `sudo lshw -C network` it gives:

> sudo lshw -C network
>   [sudo] password for vaibhav:
>  
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>   vaibhav@vaibhav:~$

I have tried so many things like `dmesg | grep 816`

`sudo modprobe r8169`

`lspci -nn`

and many more but it didn't work.
Please tell me any command or anything that will solve my problem.
If you need any information regarding my problem feel free to ask.

The `iwconfig` shows something like this:

> enp9s0    no wireless extensions.
>   enp0s29f7u3  no wireless extensions.
>   wlp12s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Xender_AP1066"  
>      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: C8:F2:30:D4:81:F7
>   Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:on
>   lo        no wireless extensions.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Try this: `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Is there a line saying `managed=false`? Then change it to `managed=true`.  Press Ctrl+O to save the file, Ctrl+X to exit. Then `sudo systemctl restart networkmanager`. Otherwise, just press Ctrl+X to exit.

Comment: As u said i entered that command that gives the output as: `[main]`
`plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono`
`dns=dnsmasq`

`[ifupdown]`
`managed=true` 
@Jos

Comment: Strange that it should say that the device is not managed, while it certainly is. Perhaps just restart the Network Manager?

Comment: when i try to restart it as you said it says: `Failed to restart networkmanager.service: Unit networkmanager.service not found.`
@Jos

Comment: Apologies, that should be `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` with a "-".

Comment: Still showing device not managed @Jos